# Spring integration FTP recursively read files with java DSL

Tags: spring-integration, ftp-client

I want to configure a gateway with Java DSL to read all the files from a FTP server **recursively**, because they are in different folders.

How can I do it?  I´ll apreciate code examples please

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    @Bean
    public FtpOutboundGatewaySpec ftpOutboundGateway() {
        return Ftp.outboundGateway(this.ftpSessionFactory,
                AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MGET, "payload")
                .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE)
                .regexFileNameFilter("(subFtpSource|.*1.txt)")
                .localDirectoryExpression("@ftpServer.targetLocalDirectoryName + #remoteDirectory")
                .localFilenameExpression("#remoteFileName.replaceFirst('ftpSource', 'localTarget')");
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow ftpMGetFlow(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway<FTPFile> ftpOutboundGateway) {
        return f -> f
                .handle(ftpOutboundGateway)
                .channel(remoteFileOutputChannel());
    }

    @Bean
    public PollableChannel remoteFileOutputChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }
```

The copy/paste from the project's [test-cases](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/ftp/FtpTests.java).

Comment: How do I specify the remote directory from which I must get the files?

Comment: That is an expression for second argument for the `Ftp.outboundGateway()` factory. Typically we specify the remote path in the request message. That's why in my sample it as `"payload"`

Comment: can you give me a sample? How should the second argument be if my sftp mget should be triggered from /tmp/remoteDirectory folder? Also, what request message? Isn't this triggered automatically if the regex finds a match?

Comment: As `'/tmp/remoteDirectory'`. What literally means "literal expression". See SpEL manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html